# Applying comma seperator formatting to an entire DataFrame in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I want to format all numbers in a DataFrame to have comma seperators (e.g. 1,000,000 instead of 1000000). It can be applied to a single number using `'{:,}'.format(number)`. Naively applying the same to a DataFrame gives the error

```
    TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

Is there a way to efficiently apply the same formatting to a DataFrame? Thanks!

Comment: Is this for presentation purposes or do you really what a new DataFrame with strings that represent the numbers with thousand separators? (and to note that `,` format will only work with integers and not floats)...

Comment: @Ninja Puppy This is for presentation purposes. And in my case they are all integers. But indeed, what you say is right about floats. Is there a way to do the same thing the DataFrame contains both integers and floats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `applymap`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, 10000, (5, 5)))

df.applymap('{:,}'.format)
```

[image]